# How to convert WETH back to ETH (solidity)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, uniswap, wrapped-tokens

I am trying to convert back WETH into ETH (actually BNB on BSC). I am doing the following:

```
    function allToBNB() public{
        WETH.transfer(address(this), WETH.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }`
```

In my constructor I defined `WETH`:

```
    IWETH private WETH;

    constructor() public{
        pancakeRouter = PancakeRouter(PANCAKESWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
        WETH = IWETH(pancakeRouter.WETH());
        require(WETH.approve(address(pancakeRouter), 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935), 'approve failed.');
    }
```

And the interface for `WETH` is:

```
interface IWETH {
    function deposit() external payable;
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
}
```

However, when I call `allToBNB`, I see a self transfer of all my WBNB balance to myself (the contract) instead of it unwrapping back into BNB (https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x60be76d6c0574ad549e98c678eb8ea9e668d96192926a9e71995ff69be0f863d).

Maybe I need to call the withdraw function? but this seems to use the msg.address instead of the contract address for the return.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert WBNB to BNB you have to call `withdraw` from [WBNB contract](https://bscscan.com/address/0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c#code)

```
function withdraw(uint wad) public {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= wad);
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= wad;
    msg.sender.transfer(wad);
    Withdrawal(msg.sender, wad);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I tried at first but was getting an error. I discovered it was because I had a non trivial fallback function, I replaced it with a empty one and now it works.